# Origin IP exposed on cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

So I have a VPS, 2 domains (one domain just forwards to the main domain name), one with 3 sub domains, all behind cloudflare. The VPS was bought and setup after both domains were already using cloudflares nameservers, and then switched to the new ip. Using a site like [viewdns](http://viewdns.info) to check the domain ip history, current ip, whois etc, I see no DNS leak and cannot see the origin IP. The main site is built upon laravel, not using SSL, and utilizing two websocket (socket.io) servers for a chat/live updates. One of the subdomains is setup with a [pomf clone/file upload site called lolisafe.](https://github.com/WeebDev/lolisafe) (which is also a nodejs server and needs a reverse proxy setup via nginx). Second subdomain is for [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-US/) and third domain has [mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) setup on it. MX records are linked to my VPS provider, who has their own roundcube setup for email, I do not run my own webmail server on the VPS.

My question is, is it possible one of these subdomains has some exploit that can expose the origin ip? Is it the lack of SSL on the main site exposing it? If it's not either of those questions, it leads me to believe that one of the three people (one being me) with access to the server ip, has been exploited and the ip was obtained that way, which would be worst possible scenario and I fear that being the answer. Is there any other resource or tests I can use to see if I did setup something incorrectly, and leaked the ip / find the exploit? The person who obtained the ip address just constantly attacks the site and has it booted offline, and is a giant pain in the ass, just is doing it to show me he has more experience and knowledge, upset I made him leave our community, so it's a personal vendetta for him. I had contacted cloudflare, and they said that the ip, plain and simple, was obtained off site, so leaked from someone with access or gained access to a computer with access to the VPS/ip. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to protect your VPS from receiving requests "directly" you could configure your firewall to only allow traffic from Cloudflare, if that doesn't work you can still using the [WAF](https://www.cloudflare.com/waf)

In case you can't use a firewall, you could configure Nginx to only accept requests from [Cloudfare IP's](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)

Something like this could work:

```
server {
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;

  include /usr/local/etc/nginx/cloudflare-allow.conf;
  deny all;

  # the rest of your config ...
}
```

The contents of `/usr/local/etc/nginx/cloudflare-allow.conf` looks like:

```
# ipv4
allow 103.21.244.0/22;
allow 103.22.200.0/22;
allow 103.31.4.0/22;
allow 104.16.0.0/12;
allow 108.162.192.0/18;
allow 131.0.72.0/22;
allow 141.101.64.0/18;
allow 162.158.0.0/15;
allow 172.64.0.0/13;
allow 173.245.48.0/20;
allow 188.114.96.0/20;
allow 190.93.240.0/20;
allow 197.234.240.0/22;
allow 198.41.128.0/17;

# ipv6
allow 2400:cb00::/32;
allow 2405:8100::/32;
allow 2405:b500::/32;
allow 2606:4700::/32;
allow 2803:f800::/32;
allow 2c0f:f248::/32;
allow 2a06:98c0::/29;
```